# C++, can't get valid vector size with .size() function

Tags: c++, vector

I am not familiar with C++. All I did is to compress and decompress a picture with RLE(running length encoding).

Now, I am not sure whether there is something wrong with this:

```
unsigned char *compressedData = new unsigned char[size];
```

Because every time I want to go through, it stuck here. And a window pop up showing this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kolkx.png)

Hope that somebody gives advice, thanks a lot!
I have been stuck here for all day long.

Here is my wrote part:

```
unsigned char *CAppCompress::Compress(int &cDataSize) {

// You can modify anything within this function, but you cannot change the function prototype.


int i, j, n ;

unsigned int r, g, b ;
std::vector<unsigned int> rgb24;
std::vector<unsigned int> compressedDataTemp;

for(j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    for(i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        b = pInput[(i + j * width) * 3 + 0] ;   // Blue Color Component
        g = pInput[(i + j * width) * 3 + 1] ;   // Red Color Component
        r = pInput[(i + j * width) * 3 + 2] ;   // Green COlor Component
        rgb24.push_back((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b ) ;
    }
}

unsigned int count=1;

compressedDataTemp.push_back(count && 0xFF);

compressedDataTemp.push_back(rgb24[0] & 0xFF);              //b   8 bits
compressedDataTemp.push_back((rgb24[0]>> 8) & 0xFF);        //g   8 bits
compressedDataTemp.push_back((rgb24[0]>> 16) & 0xFF);       //r   8 bits



for(n = 1; n < rgb24.size(); n++) {

    while(rgb24[n]==rgb24[n-1] && count<256)
    {
        count++;
        n++;
    }

    compressedDataTemp.push_back(count && 0xFF);

    compressedDataTemp.push_back(rgb24[n] & 0xFF);              //b   8 bits
    compressedDataTemp.push_back((rgb24[n]>> 8) & 0xFF);        //g   8 bits
    compressedDataTemp.push_back((rgb24[n]>> 16) & 0xFF);       //r   8 bits

    count=1;
}

int k=0;
//cDataSize = compressedDataTemp.size() ;
int size;

size = compressedDataTemp.size();

unsigned char *compressedData = new unsigned char[size];

for(k = 0; k < size; k++)
{
    compressedData[k] = compressedDataTemp[k] & 0xFF;
}

memcpy(compressedData, pInput, size) ;

return compressedData ;     // return the compressed data
```

}

Comment: -858993460 is the debug pattern, 0xCCCCCCCC

Comment: `size` is not initialized yet! Go forward one instruction and you will see that it is not negative.

Comment: You probably had integer overflow; try using a wider integer type like `long long` or `unsigned long long` (`std::int64_t` or `std::uint64_t` with [`cstdint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)). (Edit: Nevermind, didn't notice where your breakpoint was)

Comment: next step is even more confused.   There is a access violation message. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you stop on a breakpoint, the program is in the state *before* executing that line of code.

So you're seeing `size` before the assignment, not after it.